# Python Class is Undefined?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have written the following class in my .py script. Why does it keep coming back as HTMLEasyPrinting is undefined. That's a function/class in wxPython which I imported with "import wx"

**Code:**

```
#Printer Class
class Printer(HtmlEasyPrinting):
    def __init__(self):
        HtmlEasyPrinting.__init__(self)

    def GetHtmlText(self,text):
        html_text = '<h3>Data Results:</h3><p><table border="2">'
        html_text += "<tr><td>Domain:</td><td>Mail Server:</td><td>TLS:</td><td># of Employees:</td><td>Verified</td></tr>"
        for row in root.pt.get_rows():
            html_text += "<tr>"
            for x in range(len(row)):
                html_text += "<td>"+str(row[x])+"</td>"
            html_text += "</tr>"
        return html_text + "</table></p>"

    def Print(self, text, doc_name):
        self.SetHeader(doc_name)
        self.PrintText(self.GetHtmlText(text),doc_name)

    def PreviewText(self, text, doc_name):
        self.SetHeader(doc_name)
        HtmlEasyPrinting.PreviewText(self, self.GetHtmlText(text))
```

Comment: Did you just `import wx`?

Comment: `wx.EasyHtmlPrinting`?!

Comment: I tried and got, No module named 'wx.EasyHtmlPrinting

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes but so far import wx.EasyHtmlPrinting, from wx import EasyHtmlPrinting and modifying my class has resulted in errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a two choices.

One, you can use the full name.

```
class Printer(wx.HtmlEasyPrinting):
```

Two, you can import the object from `wx`

```
from wx import HtmlEasyPrinting
```

Based on the [documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.html.HtmlEasyPrinting-class.html), `HtmlEasyPrinting` lives inside `wx.html`, so you need to change `wx` to `wx.html`  everywhere.

Option 1

```
import wx.html
class Printer(wx.html.HtmlEasyPrinting):
```

Option 2

```
from wx.html import HtmlEasyPrinting
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got this: ImportError: cannot import name 'HtmlEasyPrinting'

Comment: Which of the two options did you try?

Comment: The second one. The first one I have tried already and got, 'module' object has no attribute 'HtmlEasyPrinting'

Comment: @Kyle, That means that the module name is not correct and does not contain `HtmlEasyPrinting`.

Comment: I am confused then, event the documentation shows it like that.

Comment: try `from wx.html import HtmpEasyPrinting`

Comment: Aha! that was it. Should be an l and not p by the way.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in the root of `wx`, and you haven't imported it directly. Based on [the documentation](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/html/wx.html.html), you could access it with

```
import wx.html as html

class Printer(html.HtmlEasyPrinting):
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I got: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'html'

Comment: @Kyle: `import wx.html`

Comment: @Kyle frankly it'd be easier if you bothered to read the documentation yourself.